# Mysql 8.0 JDBC Conversion not supported for type java.time.Instant using JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jdbctemplate

I've a Spring Boot 2 application. I've a repository using a JdbcTemplate like this:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)
@Repository
public class DatabaseInstanceJdbcRepository {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate managementJdbcTemplate;

 public Optional<DatabaseInstance> findByTenantId(@Param("tenantId") String tenantId) {
        try {
            DatabaseInstance dbInstance = managementJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
                    "SELECT * FROM DatabaseInstance i INNER JOIN `Database` d ON d.instance_id=i.id JOIN Tenant t ON t.id=d.tenant_id WHERE t.tenantId = ?", new Object[]{tenantId}, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(DatabaseInstance.class));
            return Optional.of(dbInstance);
        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
```

My bean `DatabaseInstance` has the classical audit fields:

```
@CreatedDate
@Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Instant createdDate;

@LastModifiedDate
private Instant lastModifiedDate;
```

The method `findByTenantI` throws this exception:

```
14/04/2020 17:17:55,366 DEBUG http-nio-8082-exec-2 BeanPropertyRowMapper:301 - Mapping column 'createdDate' to property 'createdDate' of type 'java.time.Instant'
14/04/2020 17:17:55,366 DEBUG http-nio-8082-exec-2 BeanPropertyRowMapper:301 - Mapping column 'lastModifiedBy' to property 'lastModifiedBy' of type 'java.lang.String'
14/04/2020 17:17:55,366 DEBUG http-nio-8082-exec-2 JdbcUtils:238 - JDBC driver has limited support for JDBC 4.1 'getObject(int, Class)' method
java.sql.SQLException: Conversion not supported for type java.time.Instant
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getObject(ResultSetImpl.java:1380) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getObject(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.getResultSetValue(JdbcUtils.java:229) [spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper.getColumnValue(BeanPropertyRowMapper.java:378) [spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper.mapRow(BeanPropertyRowMapper.java:299) [spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:94) [spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:61) [spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:679) [spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:617) [spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:669) [spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:700) [spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:712) [spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:783) [spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at cloud.test.management.repositories.dbms.DatabaseInstanceJdbcRepository.findByTenantId(DatabaseInstanceJdbcRepository.java:52) [classes/:?]
    at cloud.test.management.repositories.dbms.DatabaseInstanceJdbcRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$947b2b1f.invoke(<generated>) [classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) [spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) [spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) [spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) [spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) [spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) [spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at cloud.test.management.repositories.dbms.DatabaseInstanceJdbcRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c9d12814.findByTenantId(<generated>) [classes/:?]
    at cloud.test.management.caching.TenantDbCache.getDbInstance(TenantDbCache.java:52) [classes/:?]
    at cloud.test.server.tenants.ConnectionPoolManagerImpl.getDataSource(ConnectionPoolManagerImpl.java:108) [classes/:?]
    at cloud.test.server.tenants.ConnectionPoolManagerImpl.getConnection(ConnectionPoolManagerImpl.java:81) [classes/:?]
    at cloud.test.server.tenants.MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.java:38) [classes/:?]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(ContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:43) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:104) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:134) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:250) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:258) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:246) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:83) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:184) [spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:402) [spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400) [spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) [spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:572) [spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:360) [spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) [spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) [spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) [spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at cloud.test.server.security.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$361cb3c2.loadUserByUsername(<generated>) [classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:108) [spring-security-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:144) [spring-security-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:175) [spring-security-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:195) [spring-security-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:511) [spring-security-config-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at cloud.test.server.rest.controllers.security.AuthenticationRestController.createAuthenticationToken(AuthenticationRestController.java:141) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) [spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) [spring-webmvc
```

I know there is a open issue on JPA (https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jpa-api/issues/163): I'm looking for a workaround in order to solve the issue.

Answer (score -3):

add this to your imports.

```
import java.util.Date;
```

and,

```
@CreatedDate
@Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Date createdDate;

@LastModifiedDate
private Date lastModifiedDate;
```

feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't want and I can't change the type of my fields in my bean. I do want to use java.time.Instant. Thanks

Comment: in this case, you don't have to use "@CreatedDate" annotation, you can use  "@PreUpdate"
above a method and in that method update "lastModifiedDate", and use the "@PrePersist"  to update createdDate.

Comment: Thanks, I know that annotation but I fear to not understand the point to do so. Thanks